# svn unable to open an ra_local session

Tags: svn

I have set up my svn on my Linux server. I created a REPOSITORY with the following command:

```
# svnadmin create /var/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME
```

Then I set user access rights in this file:

```
# vi /var/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME/conf/svnserve.conf
```

Next, I uncomment the password-db line at line 20 and add user access

```
# vi /var/svn/REPOSITORY_NAME/conf/passwd
```

Here I add username and password.

Then I kill svn with command `# killall svnserve`
and restart it with command `# svnserve -d -r /var/svn/`

Later when I access it with the command `svn co file:///var/www/html/easton`
I get the following error:

```
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///var/www/html/easton'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the document below, you can successfully install svn/websvn (my platform is ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Install required packages

```
apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn
```

create a root directory to store svn repositories

```
mkdir /var/sourcecontrol/svn
```

create a svn repository “newrepo”

```
svnadmin create /var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo
```

create a group “subversion”

```
groupadd subversion
```

add a user and 'www-data' user to group

```
chown username:subversion -R /var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo
```

ACCESS METHODS

1.for 'file' access to repository

```
svn co file:///var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo/
```

1. for http access to repository

   vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf

add the following entries at the end

```
<Location /newrepo>    
DAV svn 
SVNPath /var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo 
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Subversion repository repositoryName" 
</Location>
```

Restart apache
    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Now you can checkout the repository “newrepo” to your local folder using http

Eg:

```
svn co http://<serverip>/newrepo /home/user/Desktop/
```

you can verify the repository in browser using  `http://<serverip>/newrepo`

1. for svn access to repository

   svnserve /var/sourcecontrol/svn/

   vim /var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo/conf/svnserve.conf

add the following at the end of file

```
[general]
anon-access = none 
auth-access = write 
password-db = passwd
realm = My First Repository
```

Add authentication

```
vim /var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo/conf/passwd
```

add the user and password at the end of file

```
    username = password
```

Now you can checkout the repository “newrepo” to your local folder using svn

Eg:

```
svn co svn://<serverip>/newrepo /home/user/Desktop/
```

WEBSVN interface

```
apt-get install websvn 
apt-get install enscript
```

(before installating, create a sample repository in your root folder)

on installation give the path of existing repository when prompted.

Copy the websvn directory to apache root folder

```
cp -r /usr/share/websvn /var/www/

vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf
```

add these entries at the end (do not remove the existing entries that we have made earlier)

```
<Location /websvn/> 
Options FollowSymLinks 
order allow,deny 
allow from all 
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Subversion Repository"    
</Location>
```

for repository management in websvn, we can use tow methods

1. dpkg-reconfigure websvn

   ```
   enter the path of all repositories separated by a comma (when prompted)
   ```

   OR

   1. vim /etc/websvn/svn_deb_conf.inc

Eg:

```
<?php 
// please edit /etc/websvn/config.php 
// or use dpkg-reconfigure websvn 
$config->parentPath("/var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo"); 
$config->parentPath("/var/sourcecontrol/svn/myrepo"); 
$config->parentPath("/var/sourcecontrol/svn/myproject"); 
$config->addRepository("newrepo", "file:///var/sourcecontrol/svn/newrepo"); 
$config->addRepository("myrepo", "file:///var/sourcecontrol/svn/myrepo"); 
$config->addRepository("myproject", "file:///var/sourcecontrol/svn/myproject"); 
$config->setEnscriptPath("/usr/bin"); 
$config->setSedPath("/bin"); 
$config->useEnscript(); 
?>
```

//newrepo,myrepo,myproject are sample repositories

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you do:

```
svn co file:///var/svn/easton
```

or:

```
svn co svn://localhost/var/svn/easton
```

instead of using /var/**www/html**/easton, since you said that you created the repository in /var/svn?

Comment: Yes Roy, you are right. i create my repository at /var/svn/easton but my project at /var/www/html/easton. So how i configure it to locate at /var/www/html/easton

Comment: If you do `cd /var/www/html; svn co svn://localhost/var/svn/easton` then it should create the directory `/var/www/html/easton`.

Comment: I believe you can also use `svn co svn://localhost/var/svn/easton /var/www/html/easton`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Steps given bellow:-

1. Open terminal ( Ctrl + Alt + T )
2. Type:
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install websvn subversion libapache2-svn -y
3. Do you want to configure WebSVN now? 
   Configure later (dpkg-reconfigure-websvn)
   Select
4. sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf
5. Uncomment few lines:

   ```
   #<Location /svn> to <Location /svn>
   #DAV svn to DAV svn
   #SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn to SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn
   #AuthType Basic to AuthType Basic
   #AuthName "Subversion Repository" to AuthName "Subversion Repository"
   #AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd to AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
   #<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT> to <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
   #Require valid-user to Require valid-user
   #</LimitExcept> to </LimitExcept>
   #</Location> to </Location>
   ```

   Verify if everything is Ok:
       cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf | grep -v '#'

   ```
   <Location /svn>
       DAV svn
       SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn

       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Subversion Repository"
       AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

       <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
           Require valid-user

       </LimitExcept>

   </Location>
   ```

You can use "sed" if you know how to use this command line.

6. sudo mkdir /var/lib/svn
7. Create a repo test:
       sudo svnadmin create /var/lib/svn/mysvnreponame
       sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/svn/mysvnreponame
8. Restart Apache:
       sudo service apache2 restart
9. Add svn user:
       sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
       sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd Username

   For additional users or modify password, you can use:
       sudo htpasswd -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd Username

   Verify if every user has been created:
       cat /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd | grep Username
10. Reconfigure websvn:
        sudo dpkg-reconfigure websvn

    ```
    12.1 - Select <Yes>
    12.2 - Select <Ok>
    12.3 - Select <Ok>
    12.4 - Leave Empty & <Ok>  
    12.5 - Select <Ok>
    ```

    If you receive message:
        failed to create symbolic link '/etc/apache2/conf.d/websvn': No such file or directory

    Try fix with:
       sudo cp /etc/websvn/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/websvn.conf
       sudo a2enconf websvn
       sudo service apache2 reload
11. Test svn:
        Get IP address: ifconfig or ip addr - If you don't recognize where is the IP address, try go back to Windows.
        http://IP-address/svn/yourreponame
12. Test websvn:
        http://IP-address/websvn

Don't forget to create the most basic structure inside your repository:

```
  /trunk
  /branches
  /tags
```