# svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Tags: windows, svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn

trying to configure the svn with jenkins and getting the below error.

> Unable to access file://localhost/D:\repositories : svn: E180001:
>   Unable to open an ra_local session to URL svn: E180001: Unable to open
>   repository 'file://localhost/D:%5Crepositories'

I can access it of Jenkins.

I tried it also with the svn and http protocols, the i get this error:

> svn: E210003: Unknown host

and also with given credentials, but none of them worked.

Below is the stack trace shown in the Jenkins:

> org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E180001: Unable to open an
>   ra_local session to URL svn: E180001: Unable to open repository
>   'file://localhost/D:%5Crepositories' svn: E180001: Unable to open
>   repository 'file://localhost/D:%5Crepositories'   at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepository(FSRepository.java:796)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.testConnection(FSRepository.java:105)
>     at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:2282)
>     at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$ModuleLocation$DescriptorImpl.checkCredentialsId(SubversionSCM.java:3043)
>     at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$ModuleLocation$DescriptorImpl.doCheckCredentialsId(SubversionSCM.java:3016)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:168)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I guess this will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335742/svn-unable-to-open-an-ra-local-session

Comment: Thank you. I`m actually using windows 7. This article explains a Linux istallation. Maybe the windows equivalent would be helpful. I tried the svn co file:/// command, and i found that the problem is identical for me, but I cant operate with apt-get and the other commands in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL. You're using `file://localhost/D:\repositories`, but that's an invalid URL and that's why you can not connect to it!

You have to use only forward slashes, not backslashes in an URL. Also, the file protocol requires three slashes:

```
file:///localhost/D:/repositories
```

would be the correct URL.